# Load an LLM in multiple GPUs

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, transformer, gpu

I am doing a POC on LLM text generation. I have one AWS p3.8x instance which has 4 GPUs each of 16 GB size. I am pretty new to use LLM and GPU. When I am trying load one LLM pertained model (WizardLM) in GPU, it is saying 16 GB is not sufficient for this. So my question is how can I load the model using all 64 GB?

Comment: For AWS, you can check out SageMaker - https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/perf_train_gpu_many though I've never used personally, it's supposed to split the model up over multiple GPUs.

Answer (score 1):

Using multiple GPUs usually means that the whole model is copied into the memory of each of them. In Pytorch this is achieved with [nn.DataParallel](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.DataParallel.html) or [nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel.html). This however, is not what you want.

It is possible to load parts of a model into different GPUs and distribute the computation among them. This, however, needs specific code logic to distribute and coordinate the different parts. It is not possible to automagically split a model into parts among different GPUs.

Your options are:

- Use a smaller model that fits on 16Gb.
- Use a GPU with enough memory to fit your current model.
- Use a quantized version of your model that is small enough.
- Perform CPU inference. This may be very slow. You may check if there is a C++ implementation for your model using parallelized CPU instruction sets to make inference fast; for instance, for Llama you can use [llama.cpp](https://github.com/ggerganov/llama.cpp).